# Update using data from select

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I'm writing a login function and I need it to use very little resources, so I'm trying to make as few calls to the database as possible.

I've got the following select statement:

```
SELECT TOP (1) fldID, fldActive, fldAdmin, fldTester, fldBanned, fldLastLogin
FROM   tblUsers
WHERE  fldName=@n AND fldPass=@p
```

I need to update the `fldLastLogin` field of the selected user if `fldActive` is `true` and fldBanned is false.

Is there a way to do this update *and still have it return the user info*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a solution

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (fldID int, fldActive bit, fldAdmin bit, fldTester bit, fldBanned bit, fldLastLogin datetime)
INSERT @tbl SELECT TOP (1) fldID, fldActive, fldAdmin, fldTester, fldBanned, fldLastLogin
FROM luka42_data.luka42_luka42.tblUsers
WHERE (fldName = @n) AND (fldPass = @p)
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl)>0 AND (SELECT fldActive from @tbl)=1 AND (SELECT fldBanned from @tbl)=0
BEGIN
    UPDATE luka42_data.luka42_luka42.tblUsers SET fldLastLogin=@t;
END
SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

If someone has a faster solution please share it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `UPDATE / SET` syntax as a subquery.  [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) has excellent tutorials.

Comment: I want to know how to get information from the select statement and use it for the update and still return the selected data.